# Set title property from NSarray in CSSearchableItemAttributeSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, corespotlight

I am trying to using `CoreSpotlight` API in application , I have plist file which has a several items on it for example animals' name . So I need to set `title` string equal to on of those object , for example if users search Lion , the line name and for example its features appears on the spotlight . Here is my code :

```
- (void)setupCoreSpotlightSearch
{

    CSSearchableItemAttributeSet *attibuteSet = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc] initWithItemContentType:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeImage];


    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"animals" withExtension:@"plist"];
    NSArray *playDictionariesArray = [[NSArray alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *getNames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",playDictionariesArray];
    NSLog(@"%@",getNames) ;


    attibuteSet.title =getNames;
    attibuteSet.contentDescription = @"blah blah ";


    CSSearchableItem *item = [[CSSearchableItem alloc] initWithUniqueIdentifier:@"app name"
                                                               domainIdentifier:@"com.compont.appname"
                                                                   attributeSet:attibuteSet];
    if (item) {
        [[CSSearchableIndex defaultSearchableIndex] indexSearchableItems:@[item] completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Search item indexed");
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

The problem is `getNames` returns all names !!! how can I filter it when is user is searching an specific word from `animals.plist` 
Thanks .

EDIT [Plist Image]:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain NSArray and iterate through playDictionariesArray, creating & initialising CSSearchableItem object with that particular entry in your data source.

```
- (void)setupCoreSpotlightSearch
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"animals" withExtension:@"plist"];
    NSArray *playDictionariesArray = [[NSArray alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSMutableArray * searchableItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(object in playDictionariesArray)
    {
        CSSearchableItemAttributeSet *attibuteSet = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc] initWithItemContentType:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeImage];

        attibuteSet.title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object]; //retrive title from object and add here
        //attibuteSet.contentDescription = @"blah blah "; // retrieve description from object and add here


        CSSearchableItem *item = [[CSSearchableItem alloc] initWithUniqueIdentifier:@"app name"
                                                           domainIdentifier:@"com.compont.appname"
                                                               attributeSet:attibuteSet];
        [searchableItems addObject:item];
    }

   if (searchableItems) {
       [[CSSearchableIndex defaultSearchableIndex] indexSearchableItems:searchableItems completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (!error) {
               NSLog(@"Search item indexed");
            }
       }];  
   }
}
```

I haven't ran and tested the code.

Comment: Why did you remove `attibuteSet.title ` ?? This is my main issue and must have a value

Comment: playDictionariesArray will contain list of all the names. So you can set title as  `attributeSet.title = object`. You can check the edit.

Comment: I change object to `for(NSString *name in playDictionariesArray)` and set 
`attributeSet.title = name` but the problem is only last item of my plist file is searchable which is `Birds` I have many other animals !

Comment: Then you need iterate through to only the last object i.e. Birds. `for(NSString *name in [playDictionariesArray objectAtIndex:[playDictionariesArray count]-1])`

Comment: Thanks ! but app crashes now ! `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Can you please share structure of your plist file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93855/discussion-between-vishnu-gondlekar-and-mc-lover).

Answer (score 0):

you are not looping through each key. Use the code provided in this question.

[CoreSpotlight indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355749/corespotlight-indexing?noredirect=1#comment54756445_31355749)

Try it on a device that supports indexing. 
NOT iPhone 4/4s or iPad.

Comment: You code doesn't call `NSLog(@"Search item indexed");` at all ! it seems nothing work . I call it `self spotLightIndexing]` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Call it on viewWillAppear... But what you should do is set a bool to run only once. Otherwise it will run on every launch.